# Outer product reformulation of LU decomposition

Tags: algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination, python, outer-product

For my numerical analysis class, I wanted to implement the rather simple, in-place LU decomposition algorithm. I did this the naive way and found my code was very, very slow, because I was doing every operation in good old interpreted Python.

So I looked in some books (mainly my trusty *Numerical Linear Algebra*, by Trefethen and Bau), and found an easy way to speed up the computations, by using NumPy's `np.dot` routine. However, the algorithm is still very slow, and the book cited above mentions an outer product reformulation of the LU algorithm, which uses only one loop.

The exact statement is the following:

> Like most of the algorithms in this book, Gaussian elimination involves a triply nested loop. In Algorithm 20.1, there are two explicit `for` loops, and the third loop is implicit in the vectors $u_{j, k \colon m}$ and $u_{k,k \colon m}$. Rewrite this algorithm with just one explicit `for` loop indexed by $k$. Inside this loop, $U$ will be updated at each step by a certain rank-one outer product. This "outer product" form of Gaussian elimination may be a better starting point than Algorithm 20.1 if one wants to optimize computer performance.

Now, I've been searching for this formulation for a while now, and can't seem to find it. The main things it needs to have are

- it needs to be in-place;
- it can't use SciPy routines (NumPy is fine however)

The current code I'm using is

```
def LUfactorize(A):
    lA = len(A)
    for k in range (0, lA-1):
        for j in range(k+1, lA):
            if abs(A[j, k]) > 1e-10:
                A[j, k] /= A[k, k]
                A[j, k+1:lA] -= A[j][k] * A[k, k+1:lA]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
def LUfactorizeB(A):
    lA = len(A)
    for k in range (0, lA-1):
        A[k+1:, k] = A[k+1:, k]/A[k, k]
        A[k+1:, k+1:] -= np.outer(A[k+1:,k],A[k, k+1:])
```

which vectorizes your lines of code and thus should be faster.

Edit: Here is my time measuring:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import random, linalg
import timeit

def LU1(A):
    lA = len(A)
    for k in range(0,lA-1):
        for j in range(k+1, lA):
            if abs(A[j,k])>1e-10:
                A[j,k] /= A[k,k]
                A[j, k+1:] -= A[j][k] * A[k,k+1:lA]

def LU2(A):
    for k in range(0,len(A)-1):
        A[k+1:,k] = A[k+1:,k]/A[k,k]
        A[k+1:,k+1:] -= np.outer(A[k+1:,k],A[k,k+1:])

def tester(matrixSize):
    A = random.rand(matrixSize, matrixSize)
    A = A.T@A
    B = A.copy()
    C = A.copy()
    def test1():
        LU1(A)
    def test2():
        LU2(B)
    # warmup
    LU1(C) 
    LU2(C)
    # measure time
    time1 = timeit.timeit(test1, number=10)/10
    time2 = timeit.timeit(test2, number=10)/10    
    print("dim=%4d, LU1: %.5f, LU2: %.5f, upspeed = %2.2f"%(matrixSize, time1, time2, time1/time2))

testDimensions = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]

for k in testDimensions:
    tester(k)
```

And my measurements:

```
dim=  10, LU1: 0.00025, LU2: 0.00011, upspeed = 2.31
dim=  20, LU1: 0.00096, LU2: 0.00022, upspeed = 4.27
dim=  30, LU1: 0.00205, LU2: 0.00034, upspeed = 6.09
dim=  40, LU1: 0.00356, LU2: 0.00049, upspeed = 7.32
dim=  50, LU1: 0.00567, LU2: 0.00067, upspeed = 8.47
dim=  60, LU1: 0.00817, LU2: 0.00090, upspeed = 9.07
dim=  70, LU1: 0.01293, LU2: 0.00111, upspeed = 11.65
dim=  80, LU1: 0.01541, LU2: 0.00129, upspeed = 11.97
dim=  90, LU1: 0.01952, LU2: 0.00173, upspeed = 11.30
dim= 100, LU1: 0.02441, LU2: 0.00220, upspeed = 11.07
dim= 200, LU1: 0.09993, LU2: 0.00861, upspeed = 11.60
dim= 300, LU1: 0.23670, LU2: 0.02187, upspeed = 10.82
dim= 400, LU1: 0.38049, LU2: 0.04580, upspeed = 8.31
dim= 500, LU1: 0.52768, LU2: 0.08319, upspeed = 6.34
dim= 600, LU1: 0.75969, LU2: 0.14168, upspeed = 5.36
dim= 700, LU1: 1.02731, LU2: 0.23459, upspeed = 4.38
dim= 800, LU1: 1.34176, LU2: 0.36763, upspeed = 3.65
dim= 900, LU1: 1.68615, LU2: 0.55875, upspeed = 3.02
dim=1000, LU1: 2.08703, LU2: 0.83434, upspeed = 2.50
```

As you probably notice, the upspeed is better than I thought. :D

Comment: I don't understand why, but this code executes significantly slower on my machine than the code I was currently using...

Comment: Which python version do you use and which matrix dimensions do you have? For me this function performs faster in most cases. I have the most upspeed around matrix dimension 500 with factor 4-5 and below 100 there is not much of a difference. For bigger matrices (>1000) the upspeed is a bit more than factor 2 (this depends most likely on the cache sizes)

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.1 for matrices anywhere between size 100x100 and 1600x1600.

Comment: The execution time for these matrices is about 100 times slower than for my old code

Comment: Which datatype do you use for A?

Comment: A is an np.float64 array

Comment: I use np.ndarray. I will add my test code and output above.